How load fonts on DOM after receiving it from HTTP request (ttf file as binary format ) - Angular
I have an API which returns font file as byte array of data.
Using http client I have to make a GET request and get the output.
Can some help, how to load font to DOM?
Thanks

The basic idea is to request the font as arraybuffer, using renderer to create the elements style and text and append them to the document head,
The buffer must be converted to base64 so you can load the url, use some library for that or implement your own.
The full example can be found in here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-t2hvcg
  public loadFont(url: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).pipe(
      map((bytes) => {
        //buffer to base64
        const src = this.base64ArrayBuffer(bytes);
        const style = this.renderer.createElement('style') as HTMLStyleElement;
        const text = this.renderer.createText(`
          html, body, p {
            font-family: "Open Sans";
          }
          @font-face {
            font-family: "Open Sans";
            font-weight: 300;
            font-stretch: 100%;
            font-display: swap;
            src: url(data:font/woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,${src}) format('woff2');
            
          }
        `);
        this.renderer.setAttribute(style, 'type', 'text/css');
        this.renderer.appendChild(style, text);
        this.renderer.appendChild(document.head, style);
        return 'Font loaded';
      })
    );
  }

